Using cdk Aspects to add tags to all resources in a stack?
I am using cdk Aspects and I can see that the statement is being printed out from the visit method. However, when I try to add a Tag to each resource within my stack, nothing happens.
This is the line I have in my app.py.
cdk.Aspects.of(my_stack).add(TagsAddingAspect())

This is my aspect.py class.
import jsii
from aws_cdk import (
    IAspect, Tag, Tags
)
 
 

@jsii.implements(IAspect)
class TagsAddingAspect:
    def visit(self, node):
        print(f'{node.node.path} - {node.__class__.__name__}') # This gets printed so I know am definitely hitting the visit function for each resource.
        
        #Tags.of(node).add('aspect_test_tag', 'tag1')
        Tag('aspect_test_tag', 'tag1').visit(node)

I tried both options above to create a tag, but neither resulted in the tags being created in the stacks resources. The documentation indicates that either should work.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tagging.html
There may be a gap in my understanding... If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it! Thanks.

Tagging itself is implemented as an aspect, and thus, it is executed too late.

However, this may all change shortly, as this PR has landed in v2.172.0.
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/32097

Thanks! I saw several tutorials which indicated that it was currently possible. https://blog.jannikwempe.com/mastering-aws-cdk-aspects. I was trying to convert this from Typescript to Python. I guess I will see what happens with the PR.

It’s possible to do project wide tagging the way it’s described in the tutorial. It’s just not possible to use Tags.of as it uses Aspects itself.

Using Tags.of(my_stack).add would work - no need for an explicit Aspect.
